# ajax response returns [object] using pdo and show my query

Tags: php, jquery

getting querystring sent back with my ajax response. The ajax works i know the id is being passed and i have echo the variable in php and it show correct but when i use json encode i get a an [object] alert in my and the response looks like this

response:

```
{"queryString":"SELECT * FROM ContactInfo WHERE id = :id"}
```

php:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
if (empty($id)) {
    echo "no id";
}
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', user, pass);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM ContactInfo WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
    echo json_encode( $stmt);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

JS:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        timeout: 6000,
        data : {id: myid}, // add if using post
        dataType : 'json', //text
        crossDomain: false,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        url: requrl,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);                        
        }
```

Comment: `async: false,` :( - mind if I ask why this is false?

Comment: i had it there from another project i did ant it was needd it is not need here. updated

Comment: What's the problem? You're setting the dataType to json - jQuery is converting the Json into an object for you. Try using a debugger instead of alerting and you should see a complex object. Perhaps you meant to send back the result array not the query? Even then, it will still alert as object

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you should expect it to alert, because it is in fact an object.

Comment: the issue is not the ajax but something in the php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the result array use [fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode( $result );
```

Then jQuery will return an object here's how you can access it:

```
success: function(data) {        
      alert(data.FirstName); 
}
```

EDIT: I noticed you're just returning one row so it's not fetchAll().

Comment: that almost worked now i get [{"FirstName":"Joe","0":"Joe","LastName":"Blow","1":"Blow","website":"www.yahoo.com","2":"www.yahoo.com","PhoneNumber":"123-123-1234","3":"123-123-1234","Fax":"test","4":"test","id":"1","5":"1"}]

Comment: I edited my post try using fetch() instead since it's just one row

Comment: i was gonna ask next if there is an pdo equvalent to MYSQLI_ASSOC and you answered that thanks that is what i needed

Comment: The list of "fetch styles" is in the link there are also examples for each case. I also prefer associative in this case because it's self-documenting. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$result = $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: `execute` returns a boolean, not the database values.

Comment: Ahh, yes, it must be `fetch`. Thanks.

Comment: do i even need this $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

Comment: i tried removing that line and all i get back is false can you tell me why that is needed